# trigger AWS lambda function from SQS that already has messages in it

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

If I set a trigger for lambda function from SQS that already has messages in it, will the existing messages trigger the lambda function? or that only new arriving messages will trigger it?
If the old messages won't trigger the lambda function automatically, is there a manual way that will still trigger the lambda function to read the old messages?

**Edit:**
After testing that, the answer is YES. The existing messages do trigger the lambda function.

Comment: Give it a try, let us know what you discover!

Comment: Any messages already in the queue that haven't been read by some other process will automatically be sent to the Lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

After testing that, the answer is YES. The existing messages do trigger the lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

When the trigger is set up, the lambda function not only gets activated by new messages but also gets caught up on the backlog in the queue.